# Issue with Keypressed event in JavaFx in Java 8

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I recently updated my java 7 to java 8. I have an application that takes in the keypressed event and check whether the keypressed is a navigational key and act accordingly. 
Below is a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

My controller code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed");
    }


}
```

My FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

//I removed all the imports in this post... My original fxml has all the imports...  

<GridPane id="gridPaneId" alignment="CENTER" focusTraversable="true" 
gridLinesVisible="true" hgap="10.0" onKeyPressed="#keyPressed" prefHeight="400.0"
 prefWidth="300.0" vgap="10.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="sample.Controller" />
```

The issue is that my code completely works fine if I run it using Java 7. When I try to run it using java 8, my UI shows up without any issues but the program is not recognizing the keypressed event. What could be the reason.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: check now.I've edited the question

Comment: According to the documentation, key events should work on all nodes, so I am not seeing the issue right now. I'll look more into it tomorrow.

Comment: Any luck skiwi?... Did you try running a small example like what I've shown above?

Comment: shot in the dark, but java8 might require non private listener methods.

Comment: @aepurniet No luck...I've tried that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GridPane doesn't have the focus. Try to invoke `requestFocus` when the stage is shown.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(SampleApp.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/Sample.fxml")));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene );
        primaryStage.show();
        scene.getRoot().requestFocus();
    }
}
```